# Checking request transfer time and result transfer time from server in android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, networking, java-ee-7

I made an app in android in backend I am using google app engine java servlet module for my thesis on mobile code offloading.
I want to calculate how much time it took  to sent the request and receive the response individually.For example request time and response time.I googled a lot but not getting help in this context. Got answer for it on net  but its not for this context .Thanx ,Any help appreciated alot.

Comment: use Fiddler or Charles proxy tool to record the network traffic and see the request time and response time from tat tools.

Comment: Is there some alternative other than fiddler and Charles proxy tool?